# How to get count of Unique records from table row record in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Simple SQL question, I searched but can't seem to find the answer already asked.

I have SQL table with unique numbers in the same row and I would like to get a count of unique records in the same row. I will use it as a PHP variable later.

Please, somebody, help me to get the count of unique records.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygShz.png)

Expected result is 
Total count of 1 = 6 
Total count of 4 = 2 
Total count of 5 = 2 
Etc..

Comment: Why is it people can't post data as data? Why the screenshots all the time? I can't read that image on my phone, nor can I transcribed it easily. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't lay my hands on it so..
Unpivot using union then group by

```
with cte as
(select id,'q1' as question,question1 from <table>
union all
select id,'q2' as question,question2 from <table>
union all
select id,'q3' as question,question3 from <table>
....
)
select id,question,count(*)
from cte 
group by id,question;
```